# Binomial expansion of x is large

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have the function:

$f(x) = \frac{5}{(1+x^2)(2+x)}$

How do I find the first n terms in the expansion of f(x) if $x$ is large?

I have no issue in finding it if x is small - we convert it into partial fraction first, then expand as usual.

What is the difference between if x is large and x is small anyway?

P.S. I am new here, still figuring out how to use math jax

Comment: Try letting $x=\dfrac{1}{y}$ and then finding the Taylor series for small $y$ for $g(x) = \dfrac{5}{(1+y^{-2})(2+y^{-1})} = \dfrac{5y^3}{(1+y^2)(1+2y)}$ and then re-substitute to get a Laurent series of $f(x)$ for large $x$

Comment: On the top bar, far right, the circled "?" can take you to the Help Center, where, in the middle column, click on "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?"

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ is small, you can view your fraction as $\frac 5{2+correction terms}$ because all the terms with a factor $x$ are small.  When $x$ is large you can view your fraction as $\frac 5{x^3+correction terms}$ because terms with lower powers of $x$ are much smaller.  For large $x$ you can factor out $\frac 5{x^3}$ then expand in powers of $\frac 1x$.  You do this because $\frac 1x$ is small.

Comment: When $x$ is small, should it not be $\frac5{2+\text{correction terms}}$?

Comment: May I ask? How do I factor out the 5/x^3 in this case?

Comment: @mikhailcbh: $\frac5{\left(1+x^2\right)(2+x)}=\frac{5/x^3}{\left(1+1/x^2\right)(1+2/x)}$